# ¿ Cómo completar los datos, nulos o perdidos de las siguientes condiciones? - ¿R - Python?

Tags: python, r, excel, bucles, dataframe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Código R o Python?

columna A: completar x1; con el promedio de la columna A.      x1 = (5.1 + 4.9 + 4.7 + 5.0)/4

columna B: Completar x2, con el dato mínimo de la columna B.   x2 = 3.0

columna C: Completar x3, con el promedio de (x3-1 + x3+1)/2.   x3 = (1.9 + 1.5)/2

columna D: Completar x4, con el primer valor de  la columna.   x4 = 0.5

columna E: Completar x5 y X6, con el promedio de los datos.    x5 = (9 + 20)/2  y  x6 = (20 + 14)/2

columna F: Cambiar los valores de las filas donde la columna Dato tome A1, en la columna F por 999.

Dato     F

A1      999

A1      999

A2      28

A1      999

A2      22

Las condiciones de estos ejemplos es en un data frame.

Comment: Bienbenido a stackoverflow!. Permiteme recomendarte que le eches un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer y que intentes evitar poner imágenes lo máximo posible

Answer (score 0):

Espero sirva. (R)

```
# genero dataframe
Dato <- c("A1","A1","A2","A1","A2")
A <- c(5.1,4.9,4.7,NA,5.0)
B <- c(NA,3.0,3.2,3.1,3.6)
C <- c(1.4,1.9,NA,1.5,1.4)
D <- c(0.5,0.1,0.3,0.9,NA)
E <- c(9,NA,20,NA,14)
F <- c(10,30,28,35,22)

df <- data.frame(Dato,A,B,C,D,E,F)

# busco posiciones NAs en cada columna
na_A <- which(is.na(df$A)==TRUE) #indicador filas con NA
na_B <- which(is.na(df$B)==TRUE) #indicador filas con NA
na_C <- which(is.na(df$C)==TRUE) #indicador filas con NA
na_D <- which(is.na(df$D)==TRUE) #indicador filas con NA
na_E <- which(is.na(df$E)==TRUE) #indicador filas con NA

#columna A: completar x1; con el promedio de la columna A. x1 = (5.1 + 4.9 + 4.7 + 5.0)/4
df$A[na_A] <- mean(df$A,na.rm = TRUE)

#columna B: Completar x2, con el dato mínimo de la columna B. x2 = 3.0
df$B[na_B] <- min(df$B,na.rm = TRUE)

#columna C: Completar x3, con el promedio de (x3-1 + x3+1)/2. x3 = (1.9 + 1.5)/2
df$C[na_C] <- (df$C[na_C-1]+df$C[na_C+1])/2

#columna D: Completar x4, con el primer valor de la columna. x4 = 0.5
df$D[na_D] <- df$D[1]

#columna E: Completar x5 y X6, con el promedio de los datos. x5 = (9 + 20)/2 y x6 = (20 + 14)/2
df$E[na_E[1]] <- (df$E[na_E[1]-1]+df$C[na_E[1]+1])/2
df$E[na_E[2]] <- (df$E[na_E[2]-1]+df$C[na_E[2]+1])/2

#columna F: Cambiar los valores de las filas donde la columna Dato tome A1, en la columna F por 999.
new_F <- c(999,999,28,999,22) #genero nuevo vector
df$F <- new_F #asigno a df
```

Saludos
GSM